# Printing using JS and @media print CSS but content pushed down

Tags: css, media-queries

My content in the print preview window is displaying down about 5 or 6 lines.

Since I've already dealt with height, margin & padding, I'm unsure what's keeping it down.  I can't check with inspect because it's inside a print preview window. I'm just experimenting with a few things so no rush.  I will post an answer if I figure it out.

JS - called from onclick();

```
function print1() {
    window.print();
}
```

CSS

```
    @media print{
    body *:not(#OFP_here){
        visibility: hidden;
        height:0px;
        margin: 0px; 
        padding: 0px;            
    }
```

Update: 3 lines are due to a table that gets built by JS, even though I have accounted for the table in @media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`visibility: hidden;` will "hide"  those elements in the sense that their contents are hidden. But the space they occupy without that rule will still appear as empty space, which I suppose is what you are referring to.

Use `display: none` instead, which will actually hide the affected elements and not leave any empty space.

Comment: Bingo!  Thanks, I learned something today.

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the `@page` which will be what modifies the global page settings.  You can read more about it here at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page)

> ### @page
>
> The @page CSS at-rule is used to modify some CSS properties when printing a document.
>
> #### Syntax
>
> ```
> @page {
>   margin: 1cm;
> }
> ```